# Mathematica list output

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica is giving me a weird output when I am asking for a specific element of a nested list.

I have:

```
testroots = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

When I ask for

```
testroots[[0,0]]
```

which should give me a 0, instead *Mathematica* says

```
Symbol
```

I don't understand why this is or what I've done wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: List elements are counted starting from 1, not zero. Try `testroots[[1,1]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica indices start with 1, not zero. So the [[0,0]] entry of testroots doesn't exist. You can get the first element using

```
testroots[[1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

As b.gatessucks and bill s already wrote, Mathematica lists start at Index 1. However the index 0 is also allowed and gives the `Head` of the expression. Now what does that mean?

Well, a list `{a,b,c}` in Mathematica is internally an expression of the Form `List[a, b, c]`. You can see that by applying `FullForm` to it:

```
FullForm[{a, b, c}]
(*
==> List[a, b, c]
*)
```

Thhe part in front of the opening bracket, here `List`, is called the head of the expression. And `testroots[[0]]` is equivalent to `Head[testroots]` which gives `List` for a list. Which makes sense, given that in the complete expression, the `List` precedes the elements.

However what about your expression `testroots[[0,0]]`? It accesses the head of the head of your list. The head of your list is `List`. But what is the head of `List`? After all, it doesn't have the form `Head[arg1, arg2, ...]`.

For atomic expressions, Mathematica gives a symbol describing the *type* of the atom. For example `Head[1]` is `Integer`, `Head["Hello"]` is `String` and `Head[foo]` is `Symbol` (assuming `foo` has not been assigned to). Note that the head of an expression of the above form also can be considered the type of the expression. The type of a list is `List`, and the type of `a+b`, full form `Plus[a, b]` is `Plus`, that is, a sum.

Now `List` is a symbol, and therefore `Head[List]` is `Symbol`. Therefore for any list, like your `testroots`, `testroots[[0,0]]` will evaluate to `Symbol`.

To get the first element of the first element of the list, use `testroots[[1,1]]`.